# decimal rounding issues for exact VAT calculation

Tags: c#

Is there a more professional way of rendering the below long-winded, convoluted attempt to extract net values and to establish the vat amount so all is equal to the starting total (tot1)

```
            decimal tot1 = Convert.ToDecimal(typeA) + Convert.ToDecimal(typeB);
            decimal netTot = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(tot1) / 1.2m, 2);
            decimal vat = tot1 - netTot;
            decimal netA = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(typeA) / 1.2m, 2);
            decimal netB = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(typeB) / 1.2m, 2);
            decimal netAA = netTot - (netA + netB);
            decimal netAAA = netAA + netA;
```

Having said that, this code works in 9 out of 10 cases. Sometimes there is a plus or minus 0.01 difference and I don't understand why

Comment: Have some sample inputs?

Comment: did you try to use string format?
I am always using this code .ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) in every computation I have, when i'm looking for 2 decimal places answers and computations. And I have no problem with this. try this code bro

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons to round values.

1. for display purposes - when you've computed a value, but now want to display it.
2. for legal purposes - when the law says VAT is rounded up to the nearest cent/pence etc.

You shouldn't round while performing calculations unless either of the above two apply.

You might want to check if VAT should be rounded to the nearest cent/pence or if it should be rounded up only. Here in Australia the GST must be rounded up to the nearest cent as the government doesn't want to miss out on those fractions of cents!!

I will assume that you need to round up. So rather than performing `Math.Round(total / 1.2m, 2)` (to get the net) I will do `Math.Ceiling(total * 100m / 6m) / 100m` (to get the VAT).

So, having said that you end up with a potential problem trying to break your figures down like this.

Say for example your inputs are `typeA = "10.47"` & `typeB = "15.27"` then computing the total VAT would be this:

```
var a_vat = Math.Ceiling(a_tot * 100m / 6m) / 100m;
var a_net = a_tot - a_vat;

var b_vat = Math.Ceiling(b_tot * 100m / 6m) / 100m;
var b_net = b_tot - b_vat;
```

Which gives:

```
a: 8.72 + 1.75 = 10.47
b: 12.72 + 2.55 = 15.27
```

Both of which add up fine.

But try and aggregate them and you get this:

```
var ab_tot = a_tot + b_tot;

var ab_vat = Math.Ceiling(ab_tot * 100m / 6m) / 100m;
var ab_net = ab_tot - ab_vat;

21.45 + 4.29 = 25.74
```

You should note that `10.47 + 15.27 = 25.74` (so the totals add up), but the separate VATs for `a` & `b` do **not** add up to the total VATs for `a + b`.

```
1.75 + 2.55 = 4.30 != 4.29
```

So, because of doing any kind of rounding on totals like this you'll get errors like this creeping in. **You cannot avoid them.**

There are two ways to tackle this.

1. Either you start with individual prices that include the VAT and you compute the total VAT by adding each component's VAT.
2. Or, you start with individual prices that do not include VAT and you compute the VAT once on the final total.

So, in the case of my example, I would do this set of calculations:

```
var a_vat = Math.Ceiling(a_tot * 100m / 6m) / 100m;
var b_vat = Math.Ceiling(b_tot * 100m / 6m) / 100m;

var ab_vat = a_vat + b_vat;

var ab_tot = a_tot + b_tot;

var ab_net = ab_tot - ab_vat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop rounding in the middle of the operation and only round the final numbers you got. The problem you are getting is when you get numbers like 0.333333 and round it before continuing the math, in my example, this would throw away 1/3 of cent.

Alright, here's an example, lets suppose that for some reason you get these values:

```
typeA = 39.5
typeB = 0.5
```

It sums up to 40. So netTot ((typeA + typeB)/1.2) would be:

```
33,333333333333333333333333333333
```

After that, you round it to 33.33.
Then, netA (typeA/1.2) and netB (typeB/1.2) would be:

```
netA = 32,916666666666666666666666666667
netB = 0,41666666666666666666666666666667
```

You rounded each to 32.92 and 0.42 respectively, which sums to 33,34, unlike the netTot that got rounded to 33.33.

As you can see, the sum of the netA and netB AFTER you rounded that screws up the math.